# How do I transition from a wood floor to tile that has a 1-1/4" height difference?

Tags: flooring, tile, hardwood-floor, transition

I have three of these transitions that I need to do something about. I thought I would be able to buy a reducer but them seem to top out around 3/4". After doing some more research it seems that I would need a ramp in this situation?

Is there something I can buy that would fix this issue?

Below is a photo of one of the transitions.

[image]

Comment: I'd have tried to do a threshold transition right at the doorway; people expect that...

Comment: What @keshlam said... a nice doorway-width hunk of oak that ramps. Know anyone with a tablesaw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a custom wood molding shop in your area (there **will** be one) and have them custom bevel a piece of 1 1/4" oak in a width that suits your fancy, then stain and varnish it. It will be more easily accomplished than you think, and the custom milling charge you will pay will be worth every penny.

*I* might just butt a narrow piece of 1 1/4" oak right up to the tile, or maybe 1 1/4" quarter-round (if you can find it). Better to just know you have to step up/down than to have a weird sloped transition.

Comment: Disagree with the second paragraph. A sloped junction is much less likely to be a tripping hazard

Comment: @keshlam, yeah... I was just thinking about how a ramped transition would jut out and cause a trip hazard from the side, if it were wide enough to provide any benefit. Best idea is prolly to cut back the tile and do a "nice doorway-width" transition, as mentioned by Aloysius Defenestrate.

Comment: Ends of the threshold piece can be started too, if you really think anyone will approach at an oblique enough angle to make tripping possible. (On the other hand, my place has at least one step transition and one threshold that is probably twice as high as it should be, and while these have caught visitors occasionally I've adjusted to them...)

Answer (score 0):

1/2" plywood, 3/4" new hardwood, right over the hardwood you have now.

Drastic-seeming, but it will truly fix the problem. You're likely to trip and fall with these bumps and jumps. Seems like a not-thought-through tile project if it raised the floor level that much. Would help if the hardwood is a small area like a hallway.

If you have rooms with hardwood all around this tile job then some long gentle ramps would be better than short/steep ramps.